# Something wrong in my checkbox validation?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I am trying to validate a form with multiple fields. Using the current js I can successfully validate every field/input except the checkboxes. I want to make sure that user submitting the form checks at least one checkbox (suites[]). For reading convenience I have deleted the other fields thus you see checkboxes only.

Below you will find τhe html form and the js:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["booking"]["name"].value;
    var surname = document.forms["booking"]["surname"].value;
    var city = document.forms["booking"]["city"].value;
    var country = document.forms["booking"]["country"].value;
    var phone = document.forms["booking"]["phone"].value;
    var email = document.forms["booking"]["email"].value;
    var arrival = document.forms["booking"]["arrival"].value;
    var departure = document.forms["booking"]["departure"].value;
    var suites = document.forms["booking"]["suites"].value;
    var persons = document.forms["booking"]["persons"].value;
    var payment = document.forms["booking"]["payment"].value;

    if (name === null || name === "" || surname === null || surname === "" || city === null || city === "" || country === null || country === "" || phone === null || phone === "" || email === null || email === "" || arrival === null || arrival === "" || departure === null || departure === "" || persons === null || persons === "" || payment === null || payment === "" || suites === null || suites === "") {
      alert("PLEASE FILL ALL REQUIRED FIELDS(*)");
      return false;
    }
var elements = document.getElementsByName('suites[]');
  var flag = false;
  for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if(elements[i].checked == true) {
         //flag = true;
          return true;
      }else{
       alert("PLEASE SELECT AT LEAST ONE SUITE(*)");
      return false;
    }
  }
  } < /script>
```

```html
<form name="booking" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="procbook.php">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Suites<span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input name="suites[]" type="checkbox" value="suite1">suite1
          </label>
          <label>
            <input name="suites[]" type="checkbox" value="suite2">suite2
          </label>
          <label>
            <input name="suites[]" type="checkbox" value="suite3">suite3
          </label>
          <label>
            <input name="suites[]" type="checkbox" value="suite4">suite4
          </label>
          <label>
            <input name="suites[]" type="checkbox" value="suite5">suite5
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I would appreciate any suggestion, advise, help.

Thanks.

Comment: The `.value` of a checkbox never changes. What changes is the `.checked` property (and it will be either `true` or `false`).

Comment: Also, you're checking for the name "suites", not "suites[]", and you're going to have a list of elements to check, not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is loop over the checkbox inputs and see if there is at least one checked. If so, I would set a flag to true. Let me show you an example:

```
function validateForm() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('suites[]');
    var flag = false;
    for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if(elements[i].checked == true) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use the `flag` to check whether or not at least one of them was true.

Comment: Hi again,
It worked like a charm, but I had to add the else condition to make it work according to my form processor. I have updated my code for future reference. Thanks.